# Outlook 2011 cannot delete account

Tags: email, crash, user-account, microsoft, office-365

Recently migrated work email to office365, therefore, all of our users have a new account on a new exchange server.

Added this without fuss, but upon trying to remove the obsolete account outlook only seems to be able to crash. Starting in safe mode does nothing.

Wonder if anyone else has run into this problem?

Comment: How are you trying to remove the accounts

Comment: Settings>accounts and remove it from there. I'm not familiar with anywhere else where you can add or remove accounts.

Comment: Have you attempted to switch to "work in offline mode" and then remove the account?  I've had similar occurrences with removing an exchange account and this did the trick.  Alternately you could create a new identity, remove the old identity, and add the new account to the new identity.

Comment: I haven't tried offline mode actually. I'll give it a shot tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Tried working offline - nothing.  Finally SUCCESS!  I unchecked the "sync to server" box that was checked and set to "every two minutes."  The constant syncing must have hung up the program.  Accounts deleted without an issue after that.  I have Outlook 2011 on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually caused due to a corrupt Outlook 2011 database.

1. Quit Outlook 2011
2. Hold down the OPTION key, and then open Outlook again -> **Microsoft Database Utility.app** shows up
3. Click the **identity** of the database that you want to rebuild, and then click **Rebuild**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue - Moved from Exchange to Exchange Online/365 and I can't remove the old account from Outlook for Mac 2011 (using Settings / Accounts / Delete). Outlook crashes every time.

Same if I go into Work Offline mode, unfortunately.

After some googling, I found this link to manually remove the account:
https://php.radford.edu/~knowledge/lore/article.php?id=400

- Shut down Outlook
- Delete the folder ~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity and its subfolders.

This will remove everything from outlook, so if you have more than the 1 account set up, they will all be deleted. But it's a clean start.
Worked for me, as I only had the old Exchange account(s) so they all needed to be deleted anyway.

Then add the O365 account back, or even better, download the new version of Outlook for Mac (2015) and use it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue I had.  Two accounts because we migrated to Office365.  Tried to remove the old account and Outlook (2011) crashed.  From then on, every time I'd try to remove the account, Outlook would crash.  My plan was to make a pst backup, and just manually remove all account info via squall's method above, but at the end of creating the pst file, Outlook crashed again.  This automatically prompted the Microsoft Database Recovery Tool to open, and it recreated her entire profile.  After this tool ran its course, I was able to delete the old email account without issue (I put Outlook in offline mode to delete the account, just in case).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Outlook 2015 and deleting the "Main Identity" folder worked for me. Except that it was in a different location:

`~/Library/Group Containers/XXXXXXXXXX.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile`

Where XXXXXXXXXX will probably be a randomly generated ID on your machine.